# python3 manage.py runserver

Tags: python, django

Having issues running django site with python3 manage.py runserver command. I have installed django-bootstrap-ui package and added the right name to my INSTALLED_APPS but still get error below:

```
(django_env)my_machine@my_pc:~/srv_django/etransphere$ python3 manage.py runserver
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x7f14d33458c8>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
fn(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 109, in inner_run
autoreload.raise_last_exception()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 249, in raise_last_exception
six.reraise(*_exception)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 685, in reraise
raise value.with_traceback(tb)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
fn(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 90, in create
module = import_module(entry)
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2224, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ImportError: No module named 'bootstrap_ui'
```

Running pip list and pip show django-bootstrap-ui both show that the package has been installed in my virtual environment

Comment: I have multiple Python version installed on my machine. All django packages I install give the same error. Trackback shows python path as "/usr/lib/python3" but all the packages are found in python2.7 directory. I think I need to point WSGI or django to use Python 2.7 as default

Comment: So it looks like the `python3` command may not be pointing to your virtualenv. Type `which python3` to confirm this. Also run `which python` -- does that point to your virtualenv?

Comment: Also, are you trying to use Python 3 or 2? You invoke the command with `python3 ...`, but your last comment says 2.7

Comment: I invoke the runserver command with python2.7 but get an error. If I however invoke it with python3 that error does not occur. But my site packages do not load with python3

Comment: The code block above shows you executing `python3 manage.py runserver` and getting an error -- that seems to contradict what you just said. Did you write down the wrong one by mistake? (Also, if you don't mind, was was the output of `which python` and `which python3`?)

Comment: (from inside the virtualenv)

Comment: @Eli Rose: From within my virtualenv     which python3    points to /usr/bin/python3
 not my virtualenv. I know that the django server or django isn't using the python library in virtualenv. How do I get it to point to python2 in my virtualenv cause that is where all my site packages are.

Comment: `python3` isn't and shouldn't point to Python 2. But `python` or `python2` might -- what is the output of `which python`?

Comment: @Eli Rose: The output of which python >> /home/a17s/django_env/bin/python. That is pointing to my virtual environment. In earlier comment, I did not mean Python3 should point to Python 2.7 rather I meant I wish to have django or the WSGI use Python 2.7 and not Python 3.

Comment: @Eli Rose: Ok, noticed a possible cause of the error. I have been running pip install on my virtualenv however running pip3 install fixes the package in the correct Python site-package directory. Will investigate further. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the problem with the msissing package when using Python3 was that I was running the installation of my packages using pip:

```
pip install django-bootstrap-ui
```

instead of pip3.

```
sudo -H pip3 install django-bootstrap-ui
```

While installing django I had used pip3 and as such the application starts off using the Python3 library and site-packages. Using pip to install any package will uncompress it files into the Python2 directory which is not being used by my django install (recall I used pip3 to install django). However, using pip3 compress the added packages into the Python3 directory which my django install uses thus can see the package. Error eliminated :D

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the errors while installing your new app in **settings.py** and **urls.py**. I had the same error after editng those files to add a new app.

**Solution:**
 Check **urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
*#this may be the place where you entered the app url but created an syntax error.*
```

And Check **settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
```

]

While you entered the app name in INSTALLED APPS list You might have Entered the wrong name

**My cause of Error:** I forgot to enter the comma after entering the app name

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'appName'  <<<<<<< 
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
```

]